# How to know the array length and put it in an integer variable in C?

Tags: c

How can I know the array length and put it in an integer variable in C?

```
int array []={1,2,3,4,5};
int arrayLength = ???????? ;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < arrayLength ;i++){
    printf("the i is :%i \n", i );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use:

```
const size_t arrayLength = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
```

The first `sizeof array` is the size (in bytes) of all of `array`, the second is the size of the first element and when divided that becomes the number of elements.

Sizes are good to keep as `size_t`, and of course it's `const` since it's not going to be changing.

Note that this code won't work if the array is passed into a function, since arrays decay into pointers in that case so you need a separate argument for the size.

Answer (score 2):

array size is constant. and **it must be known at compile time.** so you know it and you can use it in your program.

Comment: Variable length arrays, since C99, allow for arrays whose size is determined at run time.

Comment: @chux I've always got a compile error when I tried to do this in VS. that is why I said that.

Comment: The version of VS you are using likely does not conform to the C standards of C99  or C11.  Perhaps use a more compliant/up-to-date compiler?

Comment: no for example if the user input his name and you want to read his name. this example I don't know the array length.

Comment: @chux I use 2017 community and the error is this: "
Error (active) E0028 expression must have a constant value"

Comment: Do not compile C code with a C++ compiler, maybe... Even if you use VS2017 in C mode, it is still non-compliant and outdated by 25 years or so. Better to use a modern, compliant C compiler.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/compatibility) discusses some limitations of the similar earlier VS compiler.  IOWs,this answer applies to VS 2017 community C and not to the current C11 standard.

Comment: Given that error, VS 2017 still doesn't conform to C99.  It might actually conform to C11; there, VLAs are optional.  However, if it is claiming C11 compliance, the compiler should document the absence of VLAs by defining `#define __STDC_NO_VLA__ 1` to allow your code to detect that the compiler does not support VLAs.  It could also simply not support them and conform to C90 without further ado.  But it's a little depressing if MS only supports a quarter-century old standard.